# Fancybox loading video in new tab with certain videos

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a site (krelltech.com) that has a featured video on the home page.  The previous link I was using (http://krelltech.com/index2) was properly opening in fancybox.  I put a new video up (I have no control over the site hosting the new video), and its opening the video in a new tab.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that the fancybox media only works with specific media-streaming services, as per in the documentation :

- Youtube
- Vimeo
- Metacafe
- Dailymotion
- Twitvid
- Twitpic
- Instagram
- Google maps

For other servers (where you don't have control) your best bet is to open fancybox using `iframe` type mode.

Try adding a new *class* for those new videos  like

```
<a class="btn newVideo" role="button" href="http://anotherserver.com/anothervideoURL"...
```

and write a specific custom script for them like

```
$(".newVideo").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 520,
    height: 320,
    fitToView: false,
    scrolling: "no",
    autoSize : false,
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3yP3G/)**